# Passing data from input to MySQL by using Express and POST request

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, put

That's snippet of my HTML and Express code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TEST</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <form action="http://localhost:3000/tools" method="POST">
        <p>
            Set name: <input type="text" name="set_name">
        </p>
        <p>
            Description: <input type="text" name="description">
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

 </body>
</html>
```

and Express:

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const {parse}=require('querystring'); 
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'toolscatalog'
});
const app = express();
const urlParser=bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false});

function dbConnection(SQLquery, result) {
    connection.connect();
    connection.query(SQLquery, (error, results) => {
    if (error) throw error;
    result.send(results);
    console.log(results);
    });
    connection.end();
}

app.route('/tools')
    .get((req, res) => {
    dbConnection('SELECT * FROM tools', res);
    });

app.post('/tools',urlParser, (req, res) => {
    const set_name = req.body.set_name;
    const desc = req.body.description;
    console.log(set_name, desc);     //console: undefined undefined
    dbConnection(`INSERT INTO tools(set_name,description) VALUES (${set_name}, ${desc})`, res);
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on: 3000')
});
```

MySQL columns are

- id - auto-increment not null,
- set_name varchar,
- description varchar.

It seems like after submitting form, the data from the form cannot be read by bodyParser on the server. Console.log gives *undefined* values of **name** and **desc** variables.
How can I pass information from inputs to DB?

Another problem is with GET request. First request after run the server works fine. Second request to get data from DB return error and crash the server.

Comment: You are sendig `first_name` and `last_name` request params in post , how do you expect to get `set_name` and `description` ?? , do `console.log(req.body)` you will see.

Comment: I fixed that but nothing changed. Still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer for my question. ${set_name} and ${description} from SQL query should be passed as string values in quotation marks, which means "${set_name}" and "${description}".

Comment: Make sure you read up on your library about how to properly escape user input. If you just take what a user submits and string interpolate it into the SQL, you could open yourself up to SQL Injection attacks. For example, if I made my tool description be `'1'); DROP TABLE tools;` I could likely delete your entire tools table. People also use SQL Injection to steal data out of your database. Basically every sql querying library has ways for you to safely pass in user submitted values without fear of injection.